# find out 1st records after installation and boot

Tags: android, sqlite

My app is a location tracker that finds out location of a device at every 3 min. It retrives the latitude and longitude and stores it in a sqlite db. How can I find out the 1st record after installation, and 1st record after boot.
Example, I will make one more column in db for record_type. there I will store the status for code as:
installed, onboot, regular. How can this be achived.

Comment: I tried setting flags and store them in shared preferences. in OnBootReceiver as flag=1(for 1st record on boot)  and flag=2(for 1st record after after installation) I am retriving them in service. but once flage is set to a value it doesnt change. for every record it shows same flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first record after installation, you could just check the value of a [SharedPreference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), and then set the preference. For example, if "sp" is your SharedPreferences object, and you do:

```
boolean firstRecord = sp.getBoolean("firstRecord", true);
sp.edit().putBoolean("firstRecord", false).commit();
```

Then sp will contain "true" the first time you execute this code, and false the rest of the time (assuming the user does not manually clear the app's data).

For the first record after boot, you could use a [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) that receives the [ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) event. This way you can specify code that will be executed everytime the device is restarted. When you get this event, you could also work with the SharedPreferences by doing something like (sp being your SharedPreferences object):

```
sp.edit().putBoolean("justBooted", true).commit();
```

so if you do:

```
boolean firstRecordAfterBoot = sp.getBoolean("justBooted", false);
sp.edit().putBoolean("justBooted", false).commit();
```

you will know that this is the first time you execute this code after booting.